# Jquery Mobile, how to collapse a collapsible after link has been clicked? Jfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

My goal is to have the data-role collapsible, collapse after I click a tab link. Is there a solution for this or a better way to go about it? Thanks.

Here is my fiddle, notice the tabs change but the collapsible stays open, I tried to use a on click function but it didn't seem to do anything.

Any Ideas?

[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k07ghnLf/2/)

HTML

```
<div data-role="tabs">
  <div class="filter" data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
    <h4>Filter</h4>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" >
         <li><a class="collapse" href="#one" data-ajax="true">Suggested</a></li>
        <li><a  href="#two" data-ajax="false">Distance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three" data-ajax="false">Rating</a></li>
        <li><a href="#four" data-ajax="false">Open Now</a></li>
        <li><a href="five" data-ajax="false">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> 

    <div id="one" class="tablist-content">

 <!-- TAB 1  --->
 1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>

  </div>
    <div id="two" class="tablist-content" >

        <!-- TAB 2  --->
   2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br> 

    </div>
     <div id="three" class="tablist-content" >

        <!-- TAB 3  --->
   3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>

    </div>   
      <div id="four" class="tablist-content" >

        <!-- TAB 4  --->
   4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>


    </div>  

</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $(".collapse").click(function() {
        console.log("ok");
        $( ".filter" ).trigger( "collapse" );
    });

});
```

HEAD

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues going on here.  First, you have two versions of jQuery loaded.

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js

and

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

This can provide collisions, so please remove one.

Secondly, the proper code to collapse is:

```
$( ".filter" ).collapsible( "collapse" );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought I needed that second script for a geolocation function, but i deleted the second script and put the functions in the header. Now it works.